# Opening Folders

Tags: .net, vb.net, file, directory

I'm opening a folder using this code:

```
If File.Exists(fileNameAndPath) Then
  Process.Start("explorer.exe", Path.GetDirectoryName(fileNameAndPath))
End If
```

But this code keeping opening new windows of the same folder.
How can I check if folder is open first then open it.  If folder is already open then just bring it to front?
Is it possible to highlight my file it exists ?
I'm using .NET 2
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterating opened Explorer windows is possible, you have to use the [ShellWindows object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773974%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Get started with Project > Add Reference > Browse > select c:\windows\system32\shdocvw.dll

Use it like this:

```
Public Shared Sub OpenExplorerWindow(ByVal fileNameAndPath As String)
    Dim folder = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(fileNameAndPath)
    Dim target As New Uri("file://" + folder)
    Dim windows As New SHDocVw.ShellWindows
    For Each win As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer In windows
        Dim loc As New Uri(win.LocationURL)
        If loc.Equals(target) Then
            SetForegroundWindow(New IntPtr(win.HWND))
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next
    Process.Start("explorer.exe", folder)
End Sub

Private Declare Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32.dll" (hWnd As IntPtr) As Boolean
```